# JavaDoc not working in Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 3.5.2 for Android development on Ubuntu 10.04. I installed:

- Sun's JDK from Ubuntu's repositories;
- Eclipse 3.5.2 (Classic) from eclipse.org, unpacked to `/opt/eclipse`
- The Android SDK from android.com, unpacked to `/opt/android-sdk`

My problem is that when I'm in an Android project, JavaDoc will not work (neither for Android classes nor for Java classes). For example, if I hover my mouse over `DateFormat`, I get:

> **java.text.DateFormat**
>
> *Note: The Javadoc for this element could neither be found in the attached source nor the attached Javadoc.*

However, if I hover my mouse over `DateFormat` while I'm editing a normal, Java project, I do get the correct JavaDoc:

> **java.text.DateFormat**
>
> DateFormat is an abstract class for date/time formatting subclasses which formats and parses dates or time in a language-independent manner. ...

So the JavaDoc **is there**, it's just not accessible from inside Android projects, for some strange reason.

Any ideas what that reason might be?

Comment: Is probably better fit/will receive more answers viable answers on http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks.. I was thinking of posting here, but I was afraid of getting bashed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just resolved this myself, here's what I did (from inside Eclipse):

- Go to menu "Window" -> "Android SDK and AVD manager"
- Click "Available Packages" in the window that appears
- Check the "Documentation ..." package.  Note that I had only one documentation package to choose from, and it was for a newer version of the SDK than what I was using, but it was good enough.
- Click "Install Selected".

Now, just wait for the install to finish and you should have Javadoc hovers for most API calls.

Regards /J

Comment: This worked for me but FYI, I had to restart Eclipse to get the doc's to show up.

Answer (score 10):

Had the same problem even after documentation package installation.
Here how i solved the problem:

1. Go to  Project->Properties->JavaBuild path->Libraries
2. Expand Androidxxx
3. Expand android.jar
4. Select JavaDoc location and choose Edit option
5. Check if path correct

Comment: Yes, this fixed it for me. I guess having moved the sdk to another location was the cause for me.