# Javadoc for jdk1.7.0_06 not working in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, javadoc

I'm not getting the javadoc (I guess it's called) popup in Eclipse which gives details about the Java/Android method I'm currently hovered over. For instance, if I type `Log.d` and hit CTRL+SPACE there is usually a popup which shows some info about the Log.d method. This isn't happening. Any ideas how to fix it?  I recently upgraded to jdk1.7.0_06 and I think the Java docs got smoked somehow. I followed a few different threads on S.O. to try and fix it but still nothing.

I've downloaded jdk-7u6-apidocs.zip from oracle and tried loading it in `Window > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > [select jre] Edit > JavaDoc location` but when I try to validate, a popup says: *"Location might be invalid. Files 'package-list' and 'index.html' that are typically available at the root of the documentation created by the Javadoc tool have not been found"*

So then, in the same dialog above, I ticked 'Javadoc URL' and entered *"http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/"*. It validates OK, but I still don't have documentation for Log.d and others.

So, I guess how do I get the documentation popup back, and is this a java issue or android SDK issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. Follow **alphaRiv**'s solution here: [JavaDoc not working in Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858139/javadoc-not-working-in-android-project)

My path was borked so pointed it to my `android-sdk-linux/docs/reference` directory and all's well.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of pointing to JRE, you can try to point to JDK. In that way source is also be linked